# Undefined Behaviours in GCC 8.2.0/8.1.0

Tags: c++

**To meet the UB, it needs GCC 8.2.0/8.1.0 running in Windows.**

If you run the code below, you can get different outputs.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int maxn=1e5+10;
const int Mod=1e9+7;
struct Node{
    int a[10][10];
    Node(){
        memset(a,0,4*100);
    }
    inline friend Node operator * (const Node &a,const Node &b){
        Node c;
        for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<=9;j++){
                for(int k=0;k<=9;k++)
                    c.a[i][j]=(c.a[i][j]+1ll*a.a[i][k]*b.a[k][j])%Mod;
            }
        return c;
    }
};
char s[maxn];
int p1;
Node whn[110],nown[maxn];
int p2;
Node getn(int x){
    Node a;
    for(int i=0;i<=9;i++){
        if(i==0)
            a.a[i][x]=1;
        else if(i==x){
            a.a[i][x]=2;
            a.a[i][0]=Mod-1;
        }
        else
            a.a[i][i]=1;
    }
    return a;
}
Node tmp;
int main(){
    s[1]='c';
    s[2]='a';
    s[3]='e';
    s[4]='b';
    s[5]=s[6]=s[8]='g';
    s[7]=s[9]='f';
    int n=9;
    for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
        nown[0].a[i][i]=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=9;i++)
        whn[i]=getn(i);
    int ans=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=8;i++)
    {
        nown[i]=nown[i-1]*whn[s[i]-'a'+1];
        if(i<=1)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<=9;j++)
                for(int k=0;k<=9;k++)
                    ans+=nown[1].a[j][k];
        }
    }
    const int ttt=ans;
    tmp=nown[0]*whn[3];
    //nown[1]=tmp;
    for(int j=0;j<=9;j++,printf("\n"))
        for(int k=0;k<=9;k++)
            printf("%d ",nown[1].a[j][k]);
//    fprintf(stderr,"%d\n",ttt); // Whether to add this line will make the output different.
    return 0;
}
```

Actually there are some measures(any of them can make effect) to avoid the uncertain result, including:

- use `for` instead of `memset`
- use `const Node a,const Node b` instead of `const Node &a,const Node &b`

By the way, it seems that in Linux everything goes well?

It really confuses me that I can't find out problems.

Sincere Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: *it seems that in Linux everything goes well?*  Yes, **undefined behavior** can seem like everything goes well.  That is one of the reasons it is so insidious.

Comment: The `memset` clears exactly 400 bytes. If `a` is bigger or smaller than that, you get UB. Is `sizeof(int)` 4 on your system? Using a `for` loop, or `: a{0}` as the _member-initializer-list_ in the constructor, will generally be optimized to be fast memset-like code and removes any assuptions about sizes.

Comment: _What is your question?_ To figure out what the UB exactly is, and thanks for your help. @bolov

Comment: _Is `sizeof(int)` 4 on your system?_  It does be 4, and I'm also curious that whether such UB appears in certain compilers of specific versions, as it goes well in other versions of GCC?